Horror/Monster movie shown on TV in Basic Instinct
In a scene in Basic Instinct, where Nick Curran has nodded off on his sofa and is awoken when someone calls to tell him a detective he has locked horns with has been killed, there is what looks like a horror film playing on the television in front of him- does anyone recognize it?
I realize Basic Instinct itself is not on topic, but I'm going to argue the film playing on the TV in the movie, which is what I'm really asking about, is.

A timestamp would be useful

A screenshot even better.

It's about 55 minutes in. I'm pretty sure it's either Hellraiser or Hellraiser 2. I forget which and I'm on mobile at the moment.

Movies always put clip acknowledgements in the credits just like they do for music.

@lucasbachmann - They do indeed. See below, courtesy of the "End Credit Channel" on YouTube.

This is Hellraiser (1987)

A woman discovers the newly resurrected, partially formed, body of her brother-in-law and lover. She starts killing for him to revitalize his body and escape the demonic beings that are pursuing him after he escaped their underworld.

The young woman being chased in the scene shown on Nick Curran's TV at around the 55:00 mark in Basic Instinct is the protagonist, Kirsty Cotton, and  the creature chasing her is a Cenobite apparently known as the Engineer.


Basic Instinct (1992)

The Hellraiser scene occurs at around the 1:05:00 mark in that film, and you can view some brief shots of it from around the 1:00 mark in the trailer below.




The film's makers acknowledged two clips in the end credits, an episode of The Jeffersons and the 1987 movie Hellraiser.

Obviously that still leaves open the question of precisely which episode of The Jeffersons had a fanged monster chasing people around.
